# More effecient way of dealing with edit and save of entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to save and edit a record on the same screen but I think my logic is a bit messed up is their a better way of doing this using entity framework i remebmer coming across a deteached method once or twice.

```
  protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {   
   player _player = new player();

        Guid id = new Guid(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());
        Guid teamId = new Guid(Request.QueryString["teamId"].ToString());

        if (teamId != Guid.Empty)
            _player.teamId = teamId;


        if (id == Guid.Empty)
        {
            _player.Name = txtFullName.Text;
            _player.address = txtAddress.Text;
            _player.player_id = _dal.GetNextPlayerId(16, 45);
            _player.gender = dlGenders.SelectedValue.ToString();
            _dal.SoccerEntities.AddToplayers(_player);
            _dal.SoccerEntities.SaveChanges();
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Guid _playerId = new Guid(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());
            _player = _dal.GetPlayerBYID(_playerId);

            if (_player.player_id == "")
                _player.player_id = _dal.GetNextPlayerId(16, 45);
            _player.gender = dlGenders.SelectedValue.ToString();
            _player.Name = txtFullName.Text;

            _player.address = txtAddress.Text;
            _player.player_id = _dal.GetNextPlayerId(16, 45);
            _player.gender = dlGenders.SelectedValue.ToString();

            if (teamId != Guid.Empty)
                _player.teamId = teamId;



            _dal.SoccerEntities.SaveChanges();


            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");

        }
```

The secnerio is that a player may or may not exist if their already their edit their record instead of adding a new one ?.

I am also getting an error on addtoplayers

> {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_player'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.player'. The duplicate key value is (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: what is the value of `id` when you step through the code.. also `Empty.Guid` by default is this `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}` can you please show what the values are so that we can help you `refactor` your logical statement. also the error message is telling you exactly what the issue is.. you already have a value with `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}` in the primary key field and duplicates are not allowed when creating a `Primary Key`

Comment: also you should wrap the `SaveChanges` call around a `try{}catch{}` and have a single call to the Response.Redirect("default.aspx");  there are several ways to refactor this code to not have multiple calls to the same method

Comment: @MethodMan can you provide a refactor sample i had here u can use the likes of   if (EntityState == EntityState.Detached) to detech if its a new record or existing

Answer (score 1):

[Detaching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.detach(v=vs.110).aspx) will not help you in this case. You should remain attached so that change tracking can keep track of your added, modified, and deleted entities, for use in your `SaveChanges()` method.

Your primary key error could be due to your `GetNextPlayerId()` function. It appears that it is returning a default Guid(), and there is already a default Guid() in your database. Make sure it returns an unused ID, or `Guid.NewGuid()` which is nearly guaranteed to be unique.

A possibly better alternative to your `GetNextPlayerId()` function, would be to use a trigger or auto-increment attribute in your database to automatically set the key when a new row is inserted. With Entity Framework, you can then specify the  [`DatabaseGeneratedOption = Identity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption(v=vs.110).aspx) data annotation on your Entity.

For your event handler, I would remove redundancy in your code as follows.

```
   protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        player _player;

        Guid id = new Guid(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());
        Guid teamId = new Guid(Request.QueryString["teamId"].ToString());            

        if (id != Guid.Empty)
        {
            //get existing player
            _player = _dal.GetPlayerBYID(_playerId);
            if(_player == null)
                  throw new Exception(String.Format("Player: {0} not found.", _playerId));
        }
        else
        {
            //get new player
            _player = new player();
            //set key
            _player.player_id = _dal.GetNextPlayerId(16, 45);
            //add to dbset
            _dal.SoccerEntities.AddToplayers(_player);
        }

        //set properties
        if (teamId != Guid.Empty)
            _player.teamId = teamId;
        _player.Name = txtFullName.Text;
        _player.address = txtAddress.Text;
        _player.gender = dlGenders.SelectedValue.ToString();

        //save and redirect
        _dal.SoccerEntities.SaveChanges();
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
```